# Как выбрать n элементов, включая заранее известные id?

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день.

**Нужно составить SQL-запрос.**

Существует массив id:

```
$ids = array(78,8,11);  
$limit = 10;
```

Нужно выбрать `$limit` элементов из таблицы, используя SQL, включая элементы из `$ids`. И чтобы элементы из `$ids` были первыми в массиве и имели аналогичный порядок массиву `$ids`.

```
$result = array(78,8,11,..."остальные 7 шт. id");
```

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: ORDER BY FIELD ('id', 78, 8, 11)

Comment: SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY Field(id, 78, 8, 11) limit 10;
вообще не выводит ни одного из (78, 8, 11)

Если добавить DESC, то выводит, но естественно порядок меняется
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY Field(id, 78, 8, 11) DESC limit 10;

Выводит 11, 8, 78, ...

Comment: Там отсортируйте предварительно массив в обратную сторону и будет то, что надо.

Comment: спасибо всем. Работает

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Для закрепления результатов в отсортированной последовательности можно воспользоваться MySQL-функцией `FIELD`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  MyTable
ORDER BY
  FIELD(id, 11, 8, 78) DESC, id
LIMIT 10
```

Функция возвращает значение 1 для 11, 2 для 8 и 3 для 78, для остальных элементов возвращается 0. В результате идентификаторы выстраиваются в порядке

```
78
8
11
все остальные
```